# Odd behaviour from pandas str.isnumeric()

Tags: pandas

```
s1 = pd.Series([float(1), 'one1', 212, '123.3'])

s1.astype(str)
```

This outputs

```
0      1.0
1     one1
2      212
3    123.3
dtype: object
```

And this:

```
s1.astype(str).str.isnumeric()
```

outputs this:

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

I would expect all, except 'one1' to give True... why do we have this result?

Comment: the dot `.` is not a numeric character

Answer (score 0):

It is expected function [`Series.str.isnumeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html) return:

> Check whether all characters in each string are numeric.

it means `.` is not numeric.

Possible solution is create missing values to non numeric values by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `erros='coerce'` and test non missing values:

```
pd.to_numeric(s1, erros='coerce').notna()
```